# Input fields not clearing in react js application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I am trying to upload data to firebase and it is successfully adding but i want to clear the input fields too after submitting. I am very new to react js and unable to identify what gone wrong and why it is not clearing the field and please tell me i am adding data with right approch or not for going id it goes to production.
here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { database } from '../../firebase'
import { ref, push, child, update } from 'firebase/database';
const SignUp = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [repeatPassword, setrepeatPassword] = useState("");
    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { id, value } = e.target;
        if (id === "name") {
            setName(value);
        }
        if (id === "email") {
            setEmail(value);
        }
        if (id === "password") {
            setPassword(value);
        }
        if (id === "repeatPassword") {
            setrepeatPassword(value);
        }

    }
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        let obj = {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            repeatPassword: repeatPassword
        }
        // const newPostKey = push(child(ref(database), 'posts')).key;
        // const updates = {};
        // updates['/' + newPostKey] = obj
        // return update(ref(database), updates);

        const postsRef = ref(database, 'posts');
        const newPostRef = push(postsRef);
        const newPostKey = newPostRef.key;

        const updates = {};
        updates['/' + newPostKey] = obj;
        setEmail("");
        setName("");
        setPassword("");
        setrepeatPassword("");
        return update(ref(database), updates);
    }
```

Please can you spot what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your `setEmail("")` etc. does not apply on to the form, just onto the variable.
A solution would be to use refs for each of the inputs maybe.

```
const emailInput = React.useRef();

const handleSubmit = () => {
   emailInput.current.value = "";
}
```

Then when rendering the email input you have to add this:

`<input ref={emailInput} />`

Let me know if this is what you're looking for. Have a good one!

Comment: it is clearing the field but now data is not saving in firebase i wrote just before return statement

Comment: Can you explain what your return statement is for there?

Comment: I don,t know why it is there i just copied it from website explaining a sign up form. I just noticed even i remove the code of ref. It is still not uploading data. I see in network tab that request to firebase is cancelling automatically when i submit the form . Can you have any idea why it is happeining?

Comment: What is getting sent with the firebase request? Is the correct form data in the request?

Comment: yes it is same as i was sending before but i don,t know what happened now ever request to that is cancelling automaticaly

Comment: Is it cancelling or is it red (giving an error)? That could mean it has something to do with firebase